# PHP IntlDateFormatter returns incorrect year

Tags: php

I have an issue with a date conversion and after a lot of tests I don't understand what I missed.
I start with a typical datetime stored in a MySQL database (2019-12-31 09:35:16).
To be more precise, I'm on Windows with PHP 7.2.10

Here's a simple example:

```
$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter(
    'fr-FR',
    IntlDateFormatter::NONE,
    IntlDateFormatter::NONE,
    new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris'),
    IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN,
    'd/M/Y HH:mm \'UTC\'XXX'
);
echo $formatter->format(new \DateTime('2019-12-31 09:35:16'));
```

And the answer give me `31/12/2020 09:35 UTC+01:00` instead of `31/12/2019 09:35 UTC+01:00`.
After some attempts, this change on year appears also for 2013 and 2025 (and probably happens every six years...).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it appears to be down to the final parameter in the `IntlDateFormatter` method call - without that it displays the correct year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a difference in the formats. It doesn't use the [PHP date formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), it uses the [ICU date formats](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime). The y/Y formats are different:

```
Date Field Symbol Table

Symbol  Meaning                   Example(s)
y       year                      (yy or y or yyyy) 96 or 1996
Y       year of "Week of Year"    Y   1997
```

Since 2019-12-31 is on a Tuesday, it belongs to the week year of 2020. Instead, you'd use `y` for the format.

```
$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter(
    'fr-FR',
    IntlDateFormatter::NONE,
    IntlDateFormatter::NONE,
    new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris'),
    IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN,
    'd/M/y HH:mm \'UTC\'XXX'
);
echo $formatter->format(new \DateTime('2019-12-31 09:35:16'));
```